# Thread Goes in Wait or Sleep state when trying to Add rows to Datatable

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition

I created a thread which calls a webserver - reads some data - writes rows to a DataTable

My Current Thread which - waits till new rows arrive - pass the data to the system

The problem is my writer thread goes into Wait-Sleep-Join mode (came to know from thread tool window) when it tries to write rows to Datatable

The code structure is something like this:

```
class DataRetriever
{
    Thread GetReport;

    private DataTable ServerData;

    int rowCount = 0;

    private int _lastReadedRowNo = -1;

    public GetData()
    {
        thrGetReport = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fn_thrGetReport));
                thrGetReport.Name = "CallServer";
                thrGetReport.IsBackground = true;
                thrGetReport.Start();
    }

    //Writer Thread Executes this
    private void fn_thrGetReport()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            {
                DataRowCollection drcTemp = server.GetAnswer(parameter);

                for (int j = 0; j < drcTemp.Count; j++)
                {                    
                    ServerData.Rows.Add(drcTemp[j].ItemArray); // Here thread goes in Sleep/wait Mode
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref rowCount);
                }
            }

        }

    //This executes in Current Thread
     public bool Read
        {
            get
            {        
                if (no more data to ask condition)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //wait till new rows are not entered                                      
                     while (rowCount <= (_lastReadRowNo + 1) ) //Writer thread is in sleep/wait mode so this piece of code executes infinetly
                     ;                    


                    while (Condition Here)
                    {
                        // Read Datarows here 
                //Copy the Read rows to some _toReturndt
                        i++;
                    }

                    _lastReadRowNo = i - 1;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }


        public DataRowCollection GetNextData()
        {
           DataTable temp = _toReturnDt;
            _toReturnDt.Rows.Clear();
            return temp.Rows;
        }
}


public class DataProcessor
{

    public GetnProcess()
    {
        DataRetriever DataRetriever1 = new DataRetriever();
        DataRetriever1.GetData();

        while (this.DataRetriever1.Read)
        {
            DataRowCollection drc = this.DataRetriever1.GetNextData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the DataTable binded to some UI control or somewhere else?

Comment: yes its binded to datagridview ,and that why its giving me error.Thank you TcKs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, if you add row into DataTable, the DataTable will raise event. To the events are hooked UI controls from wiforms/wpf. The controls "wants do thing" after the event is raised, but the current thread is not UI thread, but the worker thread. It's the core of problem.

The solution is load data form server in worker thread, but add rows to the DataTable in UI thread.

```
DataRetriever.LoadDataFromServer( this.gridView1, this.myDataTable );
// ... elsewhere ...
public class DataRetriever {
    // uiSynchronizer can run delegates in UI thread
    // uiSynchronizer can be instance of "System.Windows.Forms.Control" (or derived) class
    public void LoadDataFromServer( ISynchronizeInvoke uiSynchronizer, DataTable target ) {
        // QueueUserWorkItem runs delegate in separated thread
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_state)=>{
            // getting rows from server
            var serverRows = server.GetAnswer(parameter);

            // addRows delegate must be called on UI thread
            Action addRows = ()=> {
                try {
                    target.BeginLoadData();
                    foreach(DataRow in serverRow in serverRows) {
                        target.Rows.Add( serverRow.ItemArray );
                    }
                }
                finally {
                    target.EndLoadData();
                }
            };

            // uiSynchronizer.Invoke runs "addRows" delegate on UI thread
            uiSynchronizer.Invoke(addRows);
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The good article about multithreading in Winforms is on CodeProject: [What's up with BeginInvoke?](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/begininvoke.aspx)